# Error en el codigo de programacion shell en Linux

Tags: linux, shell, powershell

Buenas tardes tengo un problema en la ejecucion del codigo de mi programa en shell, mi programa me pide que me de como resultado la cantidad de archivos que tienen permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecucion pero al momento de ejecutarlo me da como resultado 0 archivos con permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecucion, despues de ya haber dado varios permisos a varios archivos. Ayuda porfavor mi codigo es

```
!/bin/bash
lectura=0
echo "Archivos que tienen permisos de lectura"
for file in 'ls'; do
if [ -r $file ]
  then
   reading=$(($lectura + 1))
fi
done
echo $lectura

escritura=0
echo "Archivos que tienen permiso de escritura"
for file in 'ls'; do
if [ -w $file ]
  then
    escritura=$(($escritura +1))
fi
done
echo $escritura 

ejecucion=0
echo "Archivos que tienen permiso de ejecucion"
for file in 'ls'; do
if [ -x $file ]
  then
    ejecucion=$(($ejecucion +1))
fi
done
echo $ejecucion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo el for de esa forma, no estás colocando los archivos para pasar dentro del for... estas haciendo que el for corra una vez con `ls` como archivo:

```
$ for i in 'ls'; do echo $i; done
ls
$
```

Podrias hacerlo así:

```
for i in `ls`; do
    echo $i
done
```

O:

```
for i in $( ls ); do
    echo $i
done
```

Y, como último detalle, en vez de hacer 3 veces el `for-loop`, haz un solo `for-loop` y colocas los 3 ifs adentro de él.

Comment: Gracias fue de mucha ayuda.

Comment: No creo que fuera de mucha porque vi que pusiste la pregunta en stackoverflow _in inglish_. :-D

Comment: o `for file in *`, no hace falta parsear `ls`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' es muy cierto. bash se encarga de resolver el *. Excelente tip!